# CMake building a library with ECM

Tags: c++, cmake

I am trying to build this library https://github.com/KDE/pulseaudio-qt for a custom linux version for an embedded device created with yocto. The SDK yocto produces does not contain the extra-cmake-modules that the library needs to be build. After sourcing the environment setup script of the SDK I tried running cmake on the library:

```
-- Could NOT find ECM (missing: ECM_DIR)                                                              
--                                                                                                    
 * ECM (required version >= 5.44.0), Extra CMake Modules., <https://kde.org/products/frameworks/>     

CMake Error at /opt/board_sdk/0.6.0/sysroots/x86_64-boardsdk-linux/usr/share/cmake-3.12/Modules/FeatureSummary.cmake:459 (message):                                                                       
  feature_summary() Error: REQUIRED package(s) are missing, aborting CMake                            
  run.                                                                                                
Call Stack (most recent call first):                                                                  
  CMakeLists.txt:9 (feature_summary)
```

After that I tried installing the ECM modules manually. They ended up in `/usr/share/ECM`, so I tried setting ECM_DIR to this location before running cmake with:

```
export ECM_DIR=/usr/share/ECM
```

But the same error still occurs. Can somebody assist me in this? I have not tucked into cmake at all at this point.

Comment: Run `cmake` with `-DECM_DIR=/usr/share/ECM` instead of modifying environment.

Comment: It still tells me that it does not know ECM_DIR

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following got me past that error:

```
sudo apt install extra-cmake-modules
```

Comment: Thanks yes, I figured it out eventually. I had used the wrong cmake thus the package was not found.